# Can't name executable with specified optimization

Tags: c, gcc, optimization

I have to turn off optimizations while compiling c code I wrote while using the gcc compiler on a linux.  I have found that I can compile the code but I can only get the code to compile without the executable name specified (default to a.out).

So this works:

```
gcc -O0 Problem04b.c
```

But my problem is that I have to submit this assignment and I can't submit an executable called a.out because my instructor needs to know which problem it is.  I realize I can probably just run

```
cp a.out Problem04b
```

then

```
rm a.out
```

but I want to know if there is a way I can just compile the code directly into the executable Problem04b.  I've tried to run the command like this:

```
gcc -O0 Problem04b Problem04b.c
```

but I'm having no luck.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You rename a file using [`mv`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/mv), not `cp`+`rm`. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's the `-o` flag:

```
 gcc -O0 -o Problem04b Problem04b.c
```

Answer (score 4):

To specify the output file, you need to use the `-o <filename>` option with `gcc`.

<sup>Note : Please mind the *lower case* here</sup>

In your case, it should be

```
gcc -O0 -o Problem04b Problem04b.c
```

For reference: From [gcc manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Overall-Options.html#Overall-Options)

> -o file
>
> Place output in file file. This applies to whatever sort of output is being produced, whether it be an executable file, an object file, an assembler file or preprocessed C code.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you also want to get warnings (that won't change the produced executable, but it is very helpful to you), so compile with

```
 gcc -O0 -Wall -Wextra Problem04b.c  -o Problem04b
```

The `-Wall` option asks for nearly all warnings, the `-Wextra` option asks for even more of them.

To run your thing (the `./` is useful because of possible `PATH` issues):

```
 ./Problem04b
```

Notice that `-O0` is optional (since it is the default), you could remove it.

```
 gcc -Wall -Wextra Problem04b.c  -o Problem04b
```

If you want real optimization, e.g. for benchmarking, use e.g. `-O1` or `-O2` or `-O3`

You probably want to compile with debug information, then

```
 gcc -g -Wall -Wextra Problem04b.c  -o Problem04b
```

and of course you need to learn how to use the [GDB](http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/) debugger. So read some tutorial about that, then type

```
 gdb ./Problem04b
```

You'll get a `(gdb)` prompt. Try `help`  at that time.

You probably want to read the chapter about [invoking GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html) of the GCC documentation.

Comment: Why the downvote? I did provide useful information not given in other answers!

Comment: I don't know, but maybe it's the lack of explanation about the switches you mentioned.